# How do I achieve MAE < 8 using ResNet50 on this dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, regression, image-recognition

I've been up all night trying to achieve MAE < 8 for this age recognition dataset: [https://people.ee.ethz.ch/~timofter/publications/Agustsson-FG-2017.pdf](https://people.ee.ethz.ch/%7Etimofter/publications/Agustsson-FG-2017.pdf)

It is for an online class I am taking, the autograder checks if MAE as you can guess less than 8 and I can't get past it. The best I got is 12.9. Can you look at my code and perhaps tip me on what parameters I need to change to hit the bar?

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2

def load_train(path):
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=False,
        rescale=1/255.,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        brightness_range=[0.8, 1.2],
        shear_range=0.2,
        validation_split=0.2
    )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        pd.read_csv(f"{path}/labels.csv"),
        directory=f"{path}/final_files",
        x_col='file_name',
        y_col='real_age',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='raw',
        subset='training',
        seed=1234
    )
    print('LOAD TRAIN')
    return train_generator

def load_test(path):
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1/255.,
        validation_split=0.2
    )

    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        pd.read_csv(f"{path}/labels.csv"),
        directory=f"{path}/final_files",
        x_col='file_name',
        y_col='real_age',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='raw',
        subset='validation'
    )
    print('LOAD TEST')
    return test_generator

def create_model(input_shape):
    base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

    # Unfreeze the top layers of the model
    for layer in base_model.layers[:-15]:
        layer.trainable = False

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    initial_learning_rate = 0.001
    lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate,
        decay_steps=100000,
        decay_rate=0.96,
        staircase=True
    )

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

    print('CREATE MODEL')
    return model

def train_model(model, train_generator, test_generator, epochs=20, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None):
    history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=test_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_steps,
        shuffle=True,
        verbose=2
    )
    print('TRAIN MODEL')
    return history

# Example usage:
# train_generator = load_train('/path/to/train/data')
# test_generator = load_test('/path/to/test/data')
# model = create_model(input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
# trained_model = train_model(model, train_generator, test_generator, steps_per_epoch=100, validation_steps=50)
```